# Why does the first execution of an Ada procedure takes longer than other executions?

Tags: microcontroller, ada, riscv, gnat

I try to write a delay procedure for a FE310 microcontroller. I need to write this procedure because I use a zero footprint runtime (ZFP) that doesn't provide the native Ada delays.

The procedure rely on a 64 bits hardware timer. The timer is incremented 32768 times per second. The procedure reads the timer, calculates the final value by adding a value to the read value and then reads the timer until it reaches its final value.

I toggle a pin before and after the execution and check the delay with a logic analyzer. The delays are quite accurate except for the first execution where they are 400 us to 600 us longer than requested.

Here is my procedure:

```
procedure Delay_Ms (Ms : Positive)
is
  Start_Time : Machine_Time_Value;
  End_Time : Machine_Time_Value;
begin
  Start_Time := Machine_Time;
  End_Time := Start_Time + (Machine_Time_Value (Ms) * Machine_Time_Value (LF_Clock_Frequency)) / 1_000;

  loop
     exit when Machine_Time >= End_Time;
  end loop;
end Delay_Ms;
```

`Machine_Time` is a function reading the hardware timer.
`Machine_Time_Value` is a 64 bits unsigned integer.

I am sure the hardware aspect is correct because I wrote the same algorithm in C and it behaves exactly as expected.

I think that GNAT is adding some code that is only executed the first time.  I searched to web for mentions of a similar behavior, but didn't find anything relevant. I found some information about elaboration code and how it can be removed, but after some research, I realized that elaboration code is executed before the main and shouldn't be the cause my problem.

Do you know why the first execution of procedure like mine could take longer? Is it possible to avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: Your implementation looks fine.  One thing you can try is to look at the matching assembler code.  IIRC you pass `gcc`/`gnatmake` the argument `-S` to get an assembler dump of the compiled source text.

Comment: Cache, perhaps?

Comment: Any runtime checks?

Answer (score 1):

As Simon Wright suggested, the different first execution time is because the MCU reads the code from the SPI flash on first execution but reads it from the instruction cache on subsequent executions.

By default, the FE310 SPI clock is the processor core clock divided by 8. When I set the SPI clock divider to 2, the difference in execution time is divided by 4.